# Spock argument matching MarkupBuilder closures

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm trying to test a Groovy class which has an injected RestClient.

```
class MyService {
     def restClient

     def put() {
         restClient.put(
              path: "foo",
              contentType: "XML",
              body: { foo { bar(baz) }}
         )
     }
}
```

This works OK in manual testing.

I want to test it with Spock:

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    RESTClient restClient = Mock()

    def setup() {
        service.restClient = restClient
    }

    def "posts to restClient"() {
         when:
         service.put()

         then:
         1 * service.restClient.put([
              path: "foo",
              contentType: "XML",
              body: { foo { bar(baz) }}
         ])
    }
}
```

This fails: Spock does not consider the arguments to match. How can I make Spock recognise that they're the same arguments?

(Grails 2.3.11)

Update: I think the core of the problem is that `{ foo() } == { foo() }` is false. [How to assert equality of two closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347024/how-to-assert-equality-of-two-closures)

I see that I could capture the closures in Spock, build XML from the closures and compare the XML objects. What's a concise and readable way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _ (undescore operator) in Spock to match "anything"

```
then:
         1 * service.restClient.put(_)
```

Should probably work ok